# Rasterize (vector to raster) errors in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, rasterization

I have a point shapefile that I want to convert to a raster in QGIS, where I want to have the values from the points into pixels with a 30m x 30m resolution. But when I run the command an error happens and the following message shows up:

```
2020-11-28T12:14:10     INFO    gdal_rasterize -l None -burn 0.0 -ts 1.0 1.0 -a_nodata 0.0 -te -60.16838598138009 -4.000042531481377 -57.62922248328133 -2.0386070269701575 -ot Float32 -of GTiff file:///Volumes/New%20Volume/Thesis/Era5/Clipped_area.csv?type=csv&delimiter=,%5Ct&detectTypes=yes&xField=longitude&yField=latitude&zField=Temp_C&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no "/Volumes/New Volume/Thesis/Era5/testing_rasterize.tif"
2020-11-28T12:14:10     INFO    GDAL execution console output
             /bin/sh: /Volumes/New Volume/Thesis/Era5/testing_rasterize.tif: No such file or directory

 FAILURE: No output file specified.
 
 Usage: gdal_rasterize [-b band]* [-i] [-at]
 
  {[-burn value]* | [-a attribute_name] | [-3d]} [-add]
 
  [-l layername]* [-where expression] [-sql select_statement]
 
  [-dialect dialect] [-of format] [-a_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]*
 
  [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-a_nodata value] [-init value]*
 
  [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]
 
  [-ot {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/
 
  CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}] [-optim {[AUTO]/VECTOR/RASTER}] [-q]
```

I'm not sure what they mean by `NO OUTPUT FILE SPECIFIED`.

Then I try changing the resolution of pixels, and making the Layer extent larger, but the following shows up:

```
2020-11-28T12:24:21     INFO    gdal_rasterize -l None -burn 0.0 -ts 0.1 0.1 -a_nodata 0.0 -te -6835376.729709029 -482088.2328243251 -6308769.931712861 -143164.8265015317 -ot Float32 -of GTiff file:///Volumes/New%20Volume/Thesis/Era5/Clipped_area.csv?type=csv&delimiter=,%5Ct&detectTypes=yes&xField=longitude&yField=latitude&zField=Temp_C&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no "/Volumes/New Volume/Thesis/Era5/testing_rasterize.tif"
2020-11-28T12:24:21     INFO    GDAL execution console output
             /bin/sh: /Volumes/New Volume/Thesis/Era5/testing_rasterize.tif: No such file or directory
             
 ERROR 1: Wrong value for -outsize parameter.
 
 Usage: gdal_rasterize [-b band]* [-i] [-at]
 
  {[-burn value]* | [-a attribute_name] | [-3d]} [-add]
 
  [-l layername]* [-where expression] [-sql select_statement]
 
  [-dialect dialect] [-of format] [-a_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]*
 
  [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-a_nodata value] [-init value]*
 
  [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]
 
  [-ot {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/
 
  CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}] [-optim {[AUTO]/VECTOR/RASTER}] [-q]
```

Comment: the first thing to check is does `/Volumes/New Volume/Thesis/Era5/testing_rasterize.tif` exist? if it does then try putting `"`s around it to escape the space in the directory name

Comment: @IanTurton, good point. But now that I have tried to just "Save to temporary file" I still get an error which tells me: 
             ERROR 1: Wrong value for -outsize parameter.